# using tablet pen on the whiteboard

Tags: c++builder, whiteboard

I'm making a digital whiteboard program with C++Builder.

It draws lines on a `TImage` using `MouseDown` and `MouseMove` events, like this:

```cpp
Image1->Picture->Bitmap->Canvas->LineTo(x, y);
```

There is no problem when using the mouse.

However, when I use a Wacom tablet to draw the line, it doesn't fully recognize the movement of the pen. The problem occurs more when writing than when drawing a figure on the whiteboard.

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

What is the cause of the problem? How can I solve it?

Attached is the captured one to help you understand the problem. Same is written with mouse on the left side, and tablet pen on right side.

[image]

Code is like this:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Image1MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
    TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    MouseClick = true;
    Image1->Picture->Bitmap->Canvas->MoveTo(X,Y);
    Image1->Picture->Bitmap->Canvas->LineTo(X,Y);
    if (Pen==1){
        if(type==0)                                           //pen
        {                                                    
            Image1->Picture->Bitmap->Canvas->Pen->Color = ColorDialog1->Color;
            PenColor = ColorDialog1->Color;
        }
        else if(type==1)                                    //eraser              
        {
            Image1->Picture->Bitmap->Canvas->Pen->Color = clWhite;
            PenColor = clWhite;
        }
        Image1->Picture->Bitmap->Canvas->Pen->Width = ScrollBar1->Position;
        PenWidth = ScrollBar1->Position;
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Image1MouseMove(TObject *Sender,
    TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    if(MouseClick)
    {
        Image1->Picture->Bitmap->Canvas->LineTo(X,Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing the rest of your code in a [mcve].

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau
 added the code

Comment: Where is your `MouseUp` handler? You need to set `MouseClick=false;` when the mouse is released, so `MouseMove` won't keep drawing. Alternatively, get rid of `MouseClick` and instead check if the `Shift` parameter contains `ssLeft` or `ssPen`. Also, I suggest having the `Mouse` handlers look at the `Button` parameter and only update state when `Button` is `mbLeft`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau
Thanks a lot. I tried it, but it still doesn't work...